How to make ruler points working in StereoMorph?

For some reason my ability to add ruler points has completely disappeared in StereoMorph. (I have only been using R for about a month and have a major assignment due that I have been unable to make work due to this problem!) I've been trying for about 24 hours to get this function back and it's not working. I have tried updating software (both within R and on my whole computer) but nothing is working, so I opened up a previous project that does have ruler points already, and I would not be able to add or edit the ruler points there either?

Updating R software/StereoMorph
Updating entire computer software
Shutting computer off
Exiting R
Reading the StereoMorph CRAN guide
Reddit
Friends who use R


It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes any libraries you're using, the code you're using and sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex(). Check it out: making R reproducible questions.
